# Absolute value. Elementary number theory part of proof.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a very basic question taken from my a part of a proof in elementry number theory textbook.

My textbook states:

Given that $x\geq 0, y<0$ and $0\leq x+y$, this implies that 
$$\left| x\right| =x$$

$$\left| y\right| =-y$$

And **(Which I do not get why)**:
$$\left| x+y\right| =x+y$$

I believe that if $$y<0$$
then

$$0 < -y$$,

but if that is correct then how can 
$$\left| x+y\right| =x+y$$

Would it not only hold i:

$$\left| x-y\right| =x+y$$, since we then would have -(-y).

What am I confusing?

Comment: We are given that $0\le x+y$. Then of course $\left| x+y\right| =x+y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have: $x+y \geq 0 \Rightarrow |x+y| = x+y$, the individuals numbers $x, y$ can be negative or positive as long as their sum $x+y$ is non-negative, then you have the identity. For $|x-y|$, you have $|x-y| = x-y $ as well since $x \geq 0, -y \geq 0 \Rightarrow x-y= x + (-y) \geq 0$. Now if you want $|x-y| = x+y \iff (x-y)^2 = (x+y)^2, x +y \geq 0 \iff x^2-2xy+y^2 = x^2+2xy+y^2 \iff xy = 0  \iff x = 0 \text{ or } y = 0$, and then non-zero number $\geq 0$.